# "Add File to Blackberry Project" option is missing in Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, blackberry

I just started developing apps for the Blackberry and ran into a glitch. I was trying to add an external java class to my project in Eclipse (Version: 3.4.1) and realized that the "Add File to Blackberry Project" option was missing. I'm not sure if I missed something in the installation but I ran a sample project and it compiled and simulated fine. Can someone please help me fix this? Did I miss something in the installation? Any help is greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

According to this [blackberry support thread](http://supportforums.blackberry.com/t5/Java-Development/Add-images-to-project-with-Eclipse-Plugin/m-p/79428)

> This menu item is no longer present.  You can add resource files to your project by adding a new file using Eclipse' Import menu option.
>
> Is this a library JAR file?  If so, you can create a BlackBerry library project and convert the JAR file into a library COD file.